# How do I move the left margin further to the left to give more room to type?

Tags: spacing, margins, leftmargin

The default margin is too far over in my opinion which doesn't leave much room for typing out my long proofs I sometimes have to do. Is there a way to move the margin over to the left more?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `package` `geometry`.

Eg.:

```
\usepackage[lmargin=3cm]{geometry}
```

or

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lmargin=3cm}
```

Also, you can use other arguments as well

```
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
```

[Package documentation](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)
[Short summary and examples](https://ctan.org/pkg/geometry)